# Can Blast shoot lasers from his eyes?

Tags: one-punch-man

I've heard that in the databook Fubuki says Blast can shoot lasers from his eyes. Is this true? Can Blast shoot lasers from his eyes?

Comment: If im right there is nothing released about the power of blast

Comment: Blast this character haven't released yet, so.... gonna wait~

Answer (score 2):

I assume you've read this in the wiki since there has been no other mention about this that I could find. With that, let me quote *what was exactly written*:

> Fubuki **speculates** in the databook that Blast is stronger than King, can shoot lasers from his eyes and rules over psychic powers and the ability to command trillions of robots. She **hypothesizes** that he could beat the rest of the S-Class all at once

Notice the wording? **It's just a speculation by Fubuki.** While the info about King might be true, it was at the perspective and belief that King is the strongest man in the world (when he actually is not but Fubuki does not know this).

Comment: Nope, I've watched a youtube video from a One Punch Man youtuber who mentioned it.

Comment: You should mention your source in the question too. Also it's highly likely that the youtuber used that information from the Wikia.

Comment: @Pablo Then please link the Youtube video in your question, if you don't mind. Thanks.